# Pointers vs deep copies in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I am populating a list which I am displaying in a WPF datagrid, however, when I add the `o` object to the list I am only getting a pointer.  When I go to display in the datagrid all of the rows are identical and equal to the list record in `btcusdDepth.Asks`.  How can I ensure that record is a deep copy of the data?

```
var o = new OrderDataObject();
var bidMktOrders = new List<OrderDataObject>();
var askMktOrders = new List<OrderDataObject>();

foreach (var quote in btcusdDepth.Asks)
{
  o.orderAmt = quote.Amount.ToString();
  o.orderPrice = quote.Price.ToString();
  askMktOrders.Add(o);
}
mktDepth.ItemsSource = askMktOrders;
```

Comment: Minor technical note: You're not using pointers, but references.

Answer (score 0):

A single object exists for each time `new` is invoked, so you only have one `OrderDataObject` that you're simply updating the values to.

Do this instead:

```
var bidMktOrders = new List<OrderDataObject>();
var askMktOrders = new List<OrderDataObject>();

foreach (var quote in btcusdDepth.Asks)
{
    var o = new OrderDataObject();
    o.orderAmt = quote.Amount.ToString();
    o.orderPrice = quote.Price.ToString();
    askMktOrders.Add(o);
}
mktDepth.ItemsSource = askMktOrders;
```